# Google maps javascript v3 API - showing infowindow on mouseover of DOM element and the map keeps moving

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-listener

Like the title says, I have a directory website with profiles in the middle and a google map on the side.  I've gotten the marker infowindow to appear when you hover over the corresponding profile's div, but when the mouse moves within the div it's like the event fires over and over and the map tries to re-center the marker, giving it a jiggling effect.

Any idea how to keep this from happening?

Here is my code for the event listeners:

```js
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    markerId = "id_" + (locations[i][3]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);



    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));


    markerObj = document.getElementById(markerId);
    //you can create DOM event listeners for the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(markerObj, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

}
```

Comment: Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`

Comment: That helps.  Still doing it a little bit if you really spend some time moving the mouse around. Thanks though I think it'll be good enough